# Adding Trailing Zeros to an int field in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, append, concatenation

In the process of resequencing my web items, I am trying to append 4 zeros on the end of each item sequence number. Everything I try does not work, it seems to automatically remove the trailing zeros because of formatting. This is an int field. The only thing I got to work for 1 item as a test was actually doing a replace such as:

```
update sacatalogitem
set itm_seq = replace(itm_seq, '8021', '80210000')
where itm_id = '13' and ctg_id = '917'
```

I have tried using a cursor with the replace and it strips the trailing zeros when executing this:

```
declare @SEQ int
declare @ID int
declare @CTG int

declare cur cursor for
    select a.itm_seq, a.itm_id, a.ctg_id from sacatalogitem as a
    join saitem as b on b.itm_id = a.itm_id
    where a.cat_id = '307' and a.itm_id = '13' and a.ctg_id = '917'

open cur

fetch next from cur into @SEQ,@ID,@CTG

While (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
Begin

Update sacatalogitem
set itm_seq = replace(itm_seq, @SEQ, @SEQ + '0000')
where itm_id = @ID and ctg_id = @CTG

Update saitem
set itm_import_action = 'P'
where itm_id = @ID

fetch next from cur into @SEQ,@ID,@CTG

end

close cur
deallocate cur
```

This also fails for me:

```
update sacatalogitem
    set itm_seq = itm_seq + '0000'
    where itm_id = '13' and ctg_id = '917'
```

Any help would be appreciated for this small frustrating problem.

Comment: What would you want if itm_seq is zero (0 or 00000)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is an integer field, `MULTIPY IT BY 10000.`

```
update sacatalogitem
    set itm_seq = itm_seq * 10000
    where itm_id = '13' and ctg_id = '917'
```

Comment: unless itm_seq is zero

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
cast(cast (itemsec as varchar) + '0000' as int)
```

but frankly @VJHill 's answer is neater